# Fire - Back button event (kinda crazy scenario)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My scenario is as follows.
To [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.conduction.swipepad.android), I want to add a shortcut to SwipePad (shortcut will be my application). So when my app is launched from SwipePad, the back key is pressed on the **application that existed before**. SO basically simulating the back key on the previous application. (If that application has its own back key behavior, i want that same back key behavior executed).

For example: I launch GMail. I use swipe pad and launch facebook. I want to go back to facebook. I quickly use swipe pad to hit back key. This results in, 
1. Swipe Pad closing (This will happen).
2. facebook executing back
3. Gmail is on display

Why go through this trouble?
I use Note 2 with the SPen. Nagging scenario when, I am using SPen, and then just to go back, I have to switch from Pen to hand and back to Pen.

Coming from a dotnet background i am struggling with java and eclipse. A little help would would be appreciated.

Comment: Unlikely that you'd be able to do that because being able to hit the BACK key would be a very problematic behavior(imagine any app hitting BACK on other apps). And there's also the question of the SwipePad app somehow exposing the close event and the start of a new app.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try:

1. I honestly didn't really get what you were asking.
2. To emulate the back key, you would want to make your own "[Input Method Editor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)", the problem with that is that it will replace your current keyboard. (You can also emulate the back key if you are rooted.)
3. Instead, to solve your problem:

> I have to switch from Pen to hand and back to Pen.

You can use the SPen, hold the button on the pen, make this gesture: "<" and that will act as if you pressed the back key.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the gesture. I do not want to use that for other reasons.